# Getting two drops from a single match, how does it work?

Tags: dota-2

When you play Dota 2, after each match there is a small chance you'll get a "drop". Basically you'll get an item if you're lucky. You also get an item everytime you level up (fill the battle points bar).

Now i saw few people get 2 drops in a single match. How exactly does that work? Is it possible to get 2 or more drops just by luck, or was it more likely that they got 1 drop by luck and another drop by leveling up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can even get 3 item drops from one game,however if you manage to be that lucky you could as well go and won the lottery.

Means of getting them :

- **Level Up** - When you level up you will always get one item of random quality(no chests)
- **Random drop*** - Every game there is random chance to win one item or chest (sadly odds on chests are far greater)
- **Shopkeeper's Surprise(tool-item)**** -"When used, this Action Item gives one random item drop to a random person on the server"

*I'm not quite sure if you can get 2 chests or chest+item.

**Legendary Largesse and Breathtaking Benefaction items can award 9 and 25 random people with an item.